# Spring classpath path unit testing eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, classpath

I have been reading:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html

But am having difficulty understanding how to specify classpath resource paths.  For example I have a project structure as follows in an eclipse spring project:

```
project1
  src
    main
       resources
               maincontext.xml
    test      
       resources
               testcontext.xml
       java
           uk
             co
               project1
                      Unittest.java
```

Then in my testfile I have:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:testcontext.xml", "classpath:<path of maincontext>"})
```

public class BlacklistTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

When I right click on my test file and select debug as JUnit test, the testcontext.xml is found fine.  This makes me think the root of my classpath is "project1/src/test/resources".  I do not understand where this is determined in eclipse..?  Furthermore once I have done this, how do I include maincontext.xml if it is above my root?  And finally if I included another project 'project 2' and wanted to add a spring context file from it, how do I reference that in my unittest.java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "root" of your classpath is, literally, `""` (an empty string, consider it like a `"/"` on a filesystem).

It looks like you're using Maven. This means that things like `/src/main/java`, `/src/main/resources`, etc. get merged during the build process--in other words, Eclipse uses each as a source directory. The `test` hierarchy follows suit.

You *don't* want to include something that is "above" your root--IMO stick to classpath resources. If you don't, you must name it explicitly, leave off the `"classpath:"` prefix, since it isn't on the classpath, and provide a fully-qualified path (or as fully-qualified as your environment requires, for example, a web-app filename may be based off of the web context root, like `"/WEB-INF/foo-context.xml"`).